# How can I abbreviate the relative address using sshfs-win to map network drive?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, alias, sshfs

I tried to connect Windows-10(Client) with Linux(Host).
I successfully mapped network drive with SSHFS-Win(which is the only solution because of my company security), but I got quite long address.
`(FolderName)(\\sshfs\(user id)@(ip address)\..\..\mnt\(hdd id)`

I want to simplify the address of mapped network drive while connecting with sshfs-win.
Example : `(FolderName)(\\sshfs\(user id)@(ip address)\(Random Name))`

So I tried alias in Windows as well as Ubuntu, but it didn't work well.

In Windows, run powershell as administrator

```
set-alias MyFolder ..\..\mnt\(hdd id)
```

In Ubuntu, write on ~/.bashrc (in my account)

```
alias MyFolder='..\..\mnt\(hdd id)'
```

But both ways didn't work when typed as below.

```
net use Y: \\sshfs\(user id)@(ip address)\MyFolder
```

**How can I simplify the address of mapped network?**

Old command :
`net use Y: \\sshfs\(user id)@(ip address)\..\..\mnt\(hdd id)`

Host : Linux(ubuntu)
Client : Windows-10